# Can I execute rscript from string?

Tags: r

Can I execute rscript from string? Like this

```
> execute("d<-0") # function or command?..
> d[1]
[1] 0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
> eval(parse(text = "d<-0"))
> d[1]
[1] 0
```

But, as always:

`fortunes::fortune("answer is parse")`

> If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.    -- Thomas Lumley       R-help (February 2005)

Comment: @NelsonGon: For the record, I did not downvote your answer.

Comment: It doesn't matter, I'm mostly here to learn but I get many of these scenarios daily. It's like people are competing to be right. Not saying this was the case!

Comment: @NelsonGon: Yeah, I get what you mean. I'm probably guilty of that too, from time to time.